# Which is faster: filtering a DataSet in-memory or returning a result set from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I'm working on a pretty large table, (800k records and climbing) and I'd like to filter said table. The thing is, the table is stored in SQL Server. So, I was wondering, would a

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1=true
```

query be faster than loading the table to a typed DataSet and using DataRow.Find() then sending all those to another DataTable?

I'm guessing yes, but I'll ask anyway.

Comment: if the table is small (!) and static (doesn't usually change values) then it can make sense to load it into memory... but the case you describe: do not load the table into memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as your SQL server is not paging because of RAM starvation the SQL Server should always be faster than loading the whole table via network and then filtering locally...

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely do it in SQL Server because:

1. That's one of the things a database server is designed to do and is good at. If the condition always involves the same columns then you might want to consider adding indexes to speed up the lookup even more.
2. Performance wise it is always faster to load less data
3. Your memory consumption is going to explode when you are trying to load the whole thing into memory. Especially when the table is growing unbound. It might work ok now but can kill you unexpectedly later.

Answer (score 2):

The only exception is if you are going to be running this query over and over again.  In that case, it *might* make sense to cache the data locally and then filter it ... but even then you should only do so if performance tests indicated a significant savings.

Comment: how likely is that though? Ever run into it?

Comment: It doesn't sound common in your case ("*and climbing*"). But a good example is a relatively small (<10,000), stable, set of data, such as `Customers` or `Products`. They can be cached on the client and filtering 10,000 rows in memory is near instant.

Comment: Here's an example that I ran into a while ago - let's say you are performing tax calculations for 1000 employees.  Each employee has 10 taxes to be calculated (employee + employer).  Tax tables consist of 500,000 rows (there are over 15000 taxing jurisdictions in the US).  For each of the 10,000 tax calcs, you COULD select from the database each time.  But instead, we cached the entire set of tax tables.  This took a few seconds, but we only refreshed the cache once per day.  The net result was a savings of 10+ db hits per employee, allowing tax calcs to become real-time instead of batched.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a catch all answer really, you should test it and measure the performance for your particular circumstances.

When doing multiple complicated queries, with joins across many tables etc, we have found that it can be significantly faster to execute *one* large query into a dataset and then filter it how we need in memory.
A big part of the performance increase for us is because it avoid us doing multiple calls to the database, which can cause a bottle neck.

There are some SQL functions e.g. if you've got to do something like `WHERE LocationId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` which performs like way worse in SQL compared to doing `dataset.LocationIds.Where(id => myValues.Contains(id))` in C#, [against large datasets](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/30/in-vs-exists/), so in that situation if you measured it you should find in-memory performs best.

A `SELECT` with simple `WHERE` conditions would almost certainly be faster in SQL though. Which is why you should evaluate each scenario and test and measure if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your filter can be written as a stored procedure (you can use parameters for values in the select) it will definitely be faster because the first time you call the stored procedure its execution plan is calculated and stored.  Next call, no wait for the plan to be calculated.  (in your example however the plan calculation time is probably minuscule).

Answer (score 0):

I get that this question is old but the answers are all missing an important point.  A database can use the filter criteria, along with table indices, to **load less data from the disk**.  For example, if you were to do `SELECT * FROM X WHERE ID = 7` then (assuming `ID` is a primary key here) the database will only load a single row from the disk.  If you filtered that data on the server side then the database would need to load the entire table off the disk.

Assuming you are I/O bound this is going to give you significantly better performance.  Of course, not all filter criteria can work in this way.  It depends on the database server, indices, etc.