# Load whole database table then filter in memory, or load only filtered entries?

Tags: database, abap, opensql

I need to program a customer-search from the database.

I know databases are for managing huge amounts of data. But my "mentor" told me to interact with the db as little as possible.

Is it better to read the whole database table into an internal table and then filter based on parameters entered by the user :

```
SELECT * FROM customer INTO TABLE it_customer.

LOOP AT it_customer INTO wa.
      WHERE .... IN ...
  APPEND wa TO output.
ENDLOOP.
```

Or just do a direct access to the database table?

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
      INTO wa
      WHERE ... in ...
  APPEND wa TO output.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: The question is not related to ABAP, it's a matter of what is faster, database or application? Maybe the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755562/which-is-faster-filtering-a-dataset-in-memory-or-returning-a-result-set-from-sq) will help you.

Comment: frankly speaking, this depends on your database (esp. HANA) below. there are plenty of solutions depending on your database and your amount of data you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that DB access is considered an expensive action.
Getting used to access DB **in the right way** will absolutely give your system a performance boost.

Generally, reducing the number of DB accesses is a good starting point. However it's not the only to consider in the "**right way**" equation.

Let's have a look particularly in your case:

```
* A single DB access:
SELECT * 
  FROM customer
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_customer. 

* Then some manipualtion.
* ...
```

Pitfalls:

1. Data flow from DB to application server is expensive as said. Not only the **amount of accesses** is a factor, but also the **amount of data** being transferred. If not all customers are needed (say for a customer personal info screen), there would be a major overhead for transferring all others unneeded customers to application server.
2. Selecting the whole table may be okay if it's done only once, say in the beginning of your process. However, in many processes the DB is changed in the middle of the process (say if it's an overview screen of all customers). In that case you will have to refresh the data and doing that with another `select *` could be wrong.
3. DB access is indeed expensive, but internal manipulation is also not for free. Doing `select *` will give a starter of `N` lines in `lt_customer`, when `N` is the number of records in customer DB table. It's sometimes inevitable to make calculations in `n^2` order or even more. As the `N` grows, so is the time taking to process it.

I'm out of time now. I will try to expand more when i have more time. Good luck.

P.S. `SELECT... ENDSELECT.` is considered a bad practice. You can read about it in example [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/425112).

Answer (score 1):

The main principle which SAP states in its [performance notes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenopen_sql_perfo.htm) is:

**Keep the number of hits low**

which means that WHERE condition should NEVER be empty, like you intend to do. You should never read the whole database.

**Keep the number of reads low** principle is only on the third place, i.e. it is less important on a huge amounts of data. But also you shouldn't abuse it and should never use DB-operations in loops like your second variant does, unless you are doing something special with some special requirements.

To say more, your code violates **Keep the data volume low** principle, as you are fetching all columns instead of needed ones. Avoid using * in SELECTs unless you really use all columns.

So the answer is: **use 1st piece of code** (but with WHERE in SELECT!), it would be more efficient. In most cases ABAP operations are less expensive than DB operations.

Helpful blog on this topic:

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/21/a-complete-guide-to-opensql-statements-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT the, fields, you, really, need
  FROM customer
  INTO TABLE @DATA(customers)
  WHERE some_attribute = @some_value
    OR some_id IN @some_range.
```

If the number of records is huge, you may want to process the data in packages:

```
SELECT the, fields, you, really, need
  FROM customer
  INTO TABLE @DATA(customers)
  WHERE some_attribute = @some_value
    OR some_id IN @some_range
  PACKAGE SIZE 1024.

  " some processing

ENDSELECT
```

- Read as many records as possible in one step to keep the number of expensive database roundtrips at a minimum.
- SELECT only the really required columns and use WHERE to minimize the memory footprint and amount of data that needs to be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

## Use SELECT ... INTO TABLE

When you get a better mentor<sup>1</sup> it will be much easier to refactor your code to something reasonable.

**Only** if `it_customer` causes memory dumps should you use SELECT... ENDSELECT.

---

1) or DBA or CTO, whoever is responsible for the current, *very* bad policy